# How can I generate keypairs, and check the public key against a known public key to check for a match?

Tags: recover-private-key

Running on headless Ubuntu Linux. I would like to use [this keypair generator](https://github.com/SjorsO/keys-generator), and check the public keys generated with each run against a single other public key.

I know that "recovering" a lost private key is impossible and what not. But I'm not asking if this is a good or bad idea, I'm asking how I can accomplish the process of generating the keypairs and checking the public key. The address I'm checking against is pre-HD wallets. I don't know if that makes a difference, but may be relevant.

Consider this a proof-of-concept, demonstration.
I would like to generate the keys, compare against the known public key string, then if a match is found: record the public and private key information to a file.

I'm thinking I would grep/sed this, or maybe awk, but ultimately, need some direction.

Comment: Why not just make the function do nothing? It’ll never succeed to make a match anyway, so you save some effort.

Answer (score -1):

See [this wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address) to convert the public key to an address.